# setting php.ini to use / for webroot?

Tags: php, documentroot

New at this, so apologies if I'm not using the correct terminology, but... Locally, in my scripts, I can include scripts using:

include('/include/sample.php');

And it will automatically traverse to my web directory for inclusion... However, when I upload it to my server, it uses the server root at "/".

I don't really know what to search for, otherwise, I'd google, it, but hoping someone knows what I need to change on the server?

Comment: You need to consider that an `include` statement uses file paths, not URLs. The root as the web server sees it is not the same as the file system root. In general it's a bad idea to use absolute paths in PHP, unless you do so using variables, as per Brett's answer. If nothing else, absolute paths break portability.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the **php.ini** you might consider modifying your [include](http://php.net/include). You could use a relative path like:

```
include('include/sample.php');
```

or you could use an absolute path like:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/sample.php');
```